# Identity Server 4 (ASP.NET Core 2.2) signin-oidc and signout-callback-oidc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

To start, I'm very new to Identity Server/OIDC/OAuth2. I've hunted around to an answer to my question/our issue, but nothing seems to quite address it or responses are already based on a presumed solid foundation of Identity Server/OIDC.

We've recently ran into an issue of sorts where our users are sometimes hitting/landing and staying on `https://ourapp.domain.com/signin-oidc`. And naturally are getting a 404 error.

All of my Client configs' `RedirectUris` and `PostLogoutRedirectUris` are `https://ourapp.domain.com/signin-oidc` and `https://ourapp.domain.com/signout-callback-oidc` respectively.

At first I thought that's where our users were getting this and getting stuck, so I removed `/signin-oidc` from the uri, and then everything broke essentially. None of my client applications worked. So I replaced `/signin-oidc` and immediately they all worked again.

Our users will log in on our Identity Server, then they will be sent along to another (separate) application. And this all works when `/signin-oidc` is specific in the Client config

So where I am confused is how some users are actually landing on `/signin-oidc` and staying there. Most of the time this doesn't seem to happen.

From my understanding, `/signin-oidc` is recognized and handled by Middleware and any redirection in the process should all happen automatically.

So is there some property in `startup.cs` on the Identity Server app or the client config that I'm missing that would help this issue?

Or is there something in the client applications to configure so users don't "get stuck" on `https://ourapp.domain.com/signin-oidc` ?

**Example of one of my Client configs (and they all follow this same basic format)**

```
    clients.Add(new Client
    {

        ClientId = "demo-client",
        ClientName = "Demo Client",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ImplicitAndClientCredentials,
        AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,

        RequireConsent = false,

        ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("democlientsecret".Sha256())
            },

        // where to redirect to after login
        RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5003/signin-oidc" },

        // where to redirect to after logout
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5003/signout-callback-oidc" },

        AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                //IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                "role",
                "name",
                "idsrv-api-admin.read_only",
                "idsrv-api-admin.full_access"

            },
        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
        AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
    });
```

**`startup.cs` on Identity Server (`AddAuthentication` and `AddIdentityServerAuthentication`)**

```
        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = settings.IDServAppUrl;
                options.ApiName = settings.ApiResourceName;
                options.ApiSecret = settings.ApiResourceSecret;
                options.NameClaimType = "name";
                options.RoleClaimType = "role";
            });
```

**`startup.cs` in a client application (`AddAuthentication` and `AddOpenIdConnect`)**

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {

            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = config.IDServUrl;
                options.ClientId = config.IDServClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = config.IDServClientSecret;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("role");
                options.Scope.Add("name");
            });
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

The specific example is

1. User goes to client application URL
2. User is redirected to Identity Server's app to log in
3. User logs in
4. User goes through simple Two Factor Auth process
5. User is sent back to the sending client application based on information in the ReturnUrl query param (contains client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, etc)

It is at step 5 where users would just end up on, and stay on `https://clientapp.domain.com/signin-oidc`

After I removed `/signin-oidc` from all of my Client confgurations, trying to navigate to `https://clientapp.domain.com` would straight up fail.

Comment: What type are your clients? From your code, seems that the client you have is a server-side client (hybrid-flow). In this case your redirect url (for this client) should be the url of the page you want the users to be redirected back to. The separate page (url) is usually used for JS clients, when you are using the oidc-client-js library. Is that the case that you are hitting?

Comment: Could be CORS issue for specific browsers or something

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 Everything is ASP.NET Core MVC or Razor Pages.  `https://clientapp.domain.com/signin-oidc` would be a RedirectUri I have, and the Client App itself where users go is `https://clientapp.domain.com`. If users try to go to the Client App and are not authenticated they will be redirected to IDSrv's app to log in (with the `ReturnUrl` query param containing `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri`, etc). But if I changed the redirect_uri to remove `/signin-oidc` then I would get HTTP errors when trying to log into the client app. It wouldn't even load successfully. Does that help?

Comment: I'm surprised that you are getting errors if you remove the `signin-oidc` part. What is the IdentityServer log saying when this happens? Are you sure that you have both urls exactly the same (in the client config in IDS and in the client itself)? Some missing trailing `/` or so might cause them. That's why I'm asking about the logs

Comment: It’s likely due to an error occurring during the callback processing. There’s an event handler you can define in the middleware to allow you to take custom actions like redirecting to an error page or whatever.